# Fill Google Cloud bucket with Firebase database info?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-storage

Am I missing something? I want to have my Firebase database data loaded into a Google Cloud storage bucket. Is there a way to link Firebase and Google Cloud? I want to be able to run simple mathematical operations using the data in the cloud.

Answer (score 1):

Backing up your database to a GCS bucket is part of [Firebase's Private Backups feature](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/03/private-backups-for-firebase-data_21.html), which require that your project is on a paid plan. If it is, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/account-services/) to get is set up.